# If date = '' set date temporaraly to sysdate

Tags: mysql, date, between

I have data with begin and end date, sometimes the end date had a null and is now

```
'0000-00-00'
```

I have a query that says:

```
UPDATE w_preletter as L INNER JOIN w_prov_sensitive AS P ON L.IRS_TAX_ID = P.TAX_ID  
set L.sensitive_provider = '1', L.OFFSET_RESTRICTED = P.OFFSET_RESTRICTED 
where L.DATE_OF_SERVICE_BEG between P.BEGIN_DATE AND P.END_DATE;
```

but if the date is `'0000-00-00'` it means it is still effective so I need it to temporarily consider it the `sysdate` , otherwise it will not consider the date being in between. what would the syntax be for that? 
I don't know if its a case statement and if so how I would write it out.

Comment: why not give sample data and wished result ?

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 UPDATE w_preletter as L INNER JOIN w_prov_sensitive AS P ON L.IRS_TAX_ID = P.TAX_ID  
 set L.sensitive_provider = '1', L.OFFSET_RESTRICTED = P.OFFSET_RESTRICTED 
 where L.DATE_OF_SERVICE_BEG between P.BEGIN_DATE AND P.END_DATE 
 or (L.DATE_OF_SERVICE_BEG >= P.BEGIN_DATE AND P.END_DATE = '0000-00-00')
```

Answer (score 0):

- Create a temporary table containing all the rows in w_prov_sensitive (CREATE TABLE ... SELECT syntax)
- update the temporary table setting all END_DATE's to NOW() if they are 0/NULL/whatever
- Do the UPDATE by joining against the temporary table

You could also put boolean logic to work and use a convoluted WHERE clause.

```
where
    ( P.END_DATE != 0 and L.DATE_OF_SERVICE_BEG between P.BEGIN_DATE AND P.END_DATE )
    OR ( P.END_DATE = 0 and L.DATE_OF_SERVICE_BEG between P.BEGIN_DATE AND NOW() )
```